# When can we quantise with ladder operators?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, second-quantization, klein-gordon-equation

So I am now nearing the end of my first QFT course and in it we quantised the KleinGordon and Dirac fields using ladder operators, however this method seems very specific to these fields.

We justified it with KG by starting with a lattice and taking the continuum limit, in this case it was just harmonic oscillators at every point.  However we didn’t do that for Dirac.

The question in general is: when can we quantise with ladder operators, and if we can’t, is there a more general approach to quantisation?

Answer (score 0):

This represents the canonical way to quantize a quantum field theory. You start from a free theory (Klein-Gordon, Dirac,...) and in this way, using plane waves as fundamental solutions, you are able to introduce ladder operators. Then, you can do perturbation theory to evaluate the effects of small perturbations on the free theory.

Anyway, the most powerful approach we know today is through Feynman path integrals. You can find a nice account of all this [here](https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/ms-qft-DRAFT.pdf).